# MACVLAN Docker containers on Synology NAS with 2 VLANs cannot reach the host

Tags: networking, firewall, routing, vlan, synology

I have 2 VLANs on ETH1 port on Synology DSM 7.2. I use the MACVLAN driver, so my containers look like "seperate computers" on the network. I can reach the container from the network and I can reach the network from the container. I can even reach the container from the host, but I cannot reach the host from inside the container.

#!/bin/bash:

```
docker network create -d macvlan --subnet=10.1.40.0/24 --gateway=10.1.40.1 --ip-range=10.1.40.160/29 --aux-address 'host=10.1.40.166' -o parent=eth1.10 macvlan10
ip link add macvlan10brdg link eth1.10 type macvlan mode bridge
ip addr add 10.1.40.166/32 dev macvlan10brdg
ip link set dev macvlan10brdg up
ip route add 10.1.40.160/29 dev macvlan10brdg
docker run --net=macvlan10 -it --name macvlaneth10 --ip 10.1.40.165 --privileged --cap-add=ALL --rm alpine /bin/sh
```

ip a:

```
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:11:32:cd:8b:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: eth1.10@eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:11:32:cd:8b:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.40.16/24 brd 10.1.40.255 scope global eth1.10
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: eth1.5@eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:11:32:cd:8b:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.2.40.16/24 brd 10.2.40.255 scope global eth1.5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
14: macvlan10brdg@eth1.10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/ether 8e:3d:a4:01:5d:42 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.40.166/32 scope global macvlan10brdg
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::8c3d:a4ff:fe01:5d42/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip rule:

```
0:      from all lookup local
2:      from all lookup static-table
10:     from 10.2.40.16 lookup eth1.5-table
12:     from 10.1.40.16 lookup eth1.10-table
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

ip route:

```
default via 10.1.40.1 dev eth1.10  src 10.1.40.16
10.1.40.0/24 dev eth1.10  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.40.16
10.1.40.160/29 dev macvlan10brdg  scope link
10.2.40.0/24 dev eth1.5  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.2.40.16
```

iptables -L:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DEFAULT_FORWARD  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DEFAULT_FORWARD (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere         ****** after "iptables -I DOCKER-USER -j ACCEPT"
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward:

```
1
```

I even tried BRIDGE driver with a similar result. I can reach the container from the network and the host, I can reach the network from the container. When I try to ping the host from the container, this is what I get on the router.

```
invalid forward: in:vlan10 out:vlan10, connection-state:invalid src-mac 00:11:32:cd:8b:34, proto ICMP (type 0, code 0), 10.1.40.16->10.1.52.2, len 84
```

This is how I run the bridged container:

```
docker network create -d bridge --subnet 10.1.52.0/24 --gateway 10.1.52.1 -o parent=eth1.10 testbrgeth110
docker run --net=testbrgeth110 -it --name bridgeeth110 --privileged --cap-add=ALL --rm alpine /bin/sh
```

I spent 2 full days reading through the Internet, debugging, etc. I really have no idea what's wrong.
Bridged network on DSM 6.2 with no VLAN in the network worked like a charm.